# Calling a function with Arrays - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
//Write a program that will input letter grades (A, B, C, D, F), the number of 
//which is input by the user (a maximum of 50 grades). The grades will be read 
//into an array. A function will be called five times (once for each letter grade) 
//and will return the total number of grades in that category. The input to the 
//function will include the array, number of elements in the array and the letter
//category (A, B, C, D or F). The program will print the number of grades that 
//are A, B, etc.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double countGrade(char letterCategory, int size, char array);

const int SIZE = 5;
char letterCategory[SIZE] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'};
char userLetters[50];

int main()
{
    // Declare Variables
    int numberOfGrades = 0;
    int gradeNumbersA = 0;
    int gradeNumbersB = 0;
    int gradeNumbersC = 0;
    int gradeNumbersD = 0;
    int gradeNumbersF = 0;

    // Get the number of grades to be read
    cout << "Please input the number of grades to be read in. (1-50): ";
    cin >> numberOfGrades;

        // Input Validation
        if(numberOfGrades < 1 || numberOfGrades > 50)
        {
            cout << "Error! Invalid Input. Please enter a number between 1 and 50.\n";
            cin >> numberOfGrades;
        }
        while(numberOfGrades < 1 || numberOfGrades > 50);

        cout << "All grades must be upper case A B C D or F.\n";

    // Get the grade
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++)
        {
            cout << "Input a grade: ";
            cin >> userLetters[i];
        }
    }

    // Output the number in each category
    cout << "Number of A: " << gradeNumbersA << endl;
    cout << "Number of B: " << gradeNumbersB << endl;
    cout << "Number of C: " << gradeNumbersC << endl;
    cout << "Number of D: " << gradeNumbersD << endl;
    cout << "Number of F: " << gradeNumbersF << endl;

    return 0;
}

double countGrade(char letterCategory, int size, char array)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0;

        switch(array)
        {
        case 'A':
            a++;
            return a;
            break;
        case 'B':
            b++;
            return b;
            break;
        case 'C':
            c++;
            return c;
            break;
        case 'D':
            d++;
            return d;
            break;
        case 'F':
            f++;
            return f;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I'm not quite sure how to call the countGrade function in the main function. I know I have messed up elsewhere in this program, but I would really appreciate help with that.

Comment: First declare your function to take an array: `getGrade(char grades[]);` or `getGrade(char *grades);` then just call it with the array name: `getGrade(grades);` You could try using `Google` for a start. This is most basic C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a switch statement. Just compare the grade in the array element with the grade in the parameter. And you shouldn't return the total until the end of the function. You're returning in the loop as soon as you match one grade, so you stop looping.

```
int countGrade(char letterCategory, int size, char array[]) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        if (array[count] == letterCategory) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Then in `main()` you just do:

```
int numberOfGradesA = countGrade('A', numberOfGrades, userLetters);
```

and similarly for the other grades.